# The difference between headwords and main words

Tags: grammar, phrases

Not while ago, I was provided with a handout adressing types of phrases and in the very beginning, my lecturer stated this :[image]

Now, what I'm basically trying to know is, first: whether the info is valid (about phrases being two classes) and second: if it's actually accurate, how can we differentiate between a headword and a main word?

Comment: A rather silly sheet. All terminology with no examples and no recourse.  Meant to be memorized, rather than understood. As for validity, there is no information here, except for terminology that can be applied to anything (since there are no rules for application or context given). Some linguists may classify phrases in those ways, but others use other ways -- it's not something one discovers like the height of Kilimanjaro.

Comment: Silly or not, It's not mine and I'm not concurring to anything on it . I'm only trying to know if the sheet has some truthfulness to it or not.

Comment: As I said, some truth. There are probably some linguists who categorize phrases that way on occasion; but there are plenty of others who find those distinctions inadequate or incorrect, and use their own instead. Note that it doesn't say that this is the way things are -- it blames all this on "Grammarians", which is definitely not correct. Speaking as a grammarian, I would say that the terminology is useful, but its categorization is incomplete and misleading. This isn't even a good list to memorize.

Comment: There's no difference between 'main' word and 'head' word, though we would normally say that the NP "the guy who fainted", for example, has the noun "guy" as **head**. List 2. is odd. "Participle', 'gerund' and 'infinitive' are verb types that head non-finite clauses. 'Absolute' is not a phrase but a type of non-finite clause. Appositives, however, are NPs.